# Can't see toggle button (with bars) in navigation tab using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I writing code for making a navigation bar using bootstrap but the code doesn't show up the toggle button on the web page. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>
</nav>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: resize your window to mobile width and it will more than likely show up.  The toggle button in bootstraps menu is supposed to be used to toggle the mobile menu.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!